# Focus question title with keyboard selection

Tags: script, keyboard-shortcuts

### Description

When using the keyboard shortcuts to navigate post lists (<kbd>U</kbd> - top post; <kbd>J</kbd> - next post; <kbd>K</kbd> - previous post) this userscript will also set the focus on the hyperlink to the post.

This allows using <kbd>Enter</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the question without reaching for the mouse or excessively pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get to that element. As well as other direct interactions with the link element.

Only selects post titles in lists that link to a Q&A, such as **/questions** or **/users/{user id}/{user name}?tab=answers** The userscript has no effect when navigating posts in a Q&A.

### Installation

[Direct install (GitHub)](https://github.com/PurpleMagick/se_userscript-keyboard-select-title-focus/raw/main/src/keyboard-title-focus.user.js)

[See the code on GitHub](https://github.com/PurpleMagick/se_userscript-keyboard-select-title-focus/blob/main/src/keyboard-title-focus.user.js)

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Focus question title with keyboard selection
// @description     Focuses the title of a keyboard selected post. Allows for Ctrl+Click to open in new tab
// @author          VLAZ
// @grant           none
// @inject-into     page
// @match           https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://serverfault.com/*
// @match           https://superuser.com/*
// @match           https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match           https://askubuntu.com/*
// @match           https://stackapps.com/*
// @match           https://mathoverflow.net/*
// @match           https://pt.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ja.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ru.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://es.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match           https://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match           https://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match           https://meta.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match           https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match           https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/*
// @namespace       https://github.com/PurpleMagick/
// @run-at          document-end
// @version         1.0.0
// ==/UserScript==
(() => {
    "use strict";
    const findKeyboardSelectChange = mutation => 
        mutation.type === "attributes"
            && mutation.attributeName === "class"
            && mutation.target.classList.contains("keyboard-selected");

    const callback = mutationList => {
        const keyboardSelectedContainer = Array.prototype.find
            .call(mutationList, findKeyboardSelectChange)
            ?.target;

        if (!keyboardSelectedContainer)
            return;

        keyboardSelectedContainer.querySelector("a.s-link, a.answer-hyperlink")?.focus();
    };

    const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

    observer.observe(document.body, { 
        attributes: true,
        attributeFilter: ["class"],
        subtree: true
    });
})();
```